# sbt test using scala-cucumber runner class running but not executing scenarios

Tags: scala, sbt, cucumber

I am trying to run a program developed in scala cucumber and trying to run same via command line. This job is executed successfully via Intellij when ran Runner class but while running it via command line, it shows "No tests run"

```
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/user/.sbt/0.13/plugins
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/user/Documents/Spark-Scala/Spark_Scala_Cucumber/project
[info] Set current project to Spark_Scala_Cucumber (in build file:/Users/user/Documents/Spark-Scala/Spark_Scala_Cucumber/)
[info] Passed: Total 0, Failed 0, Errors 0, Passed 0
[info] No tests to run for test:testOnly
[success] Total time: 2 s, completed Aug 29, 2019 11:15:02 PM
```

tried following commands: 
sbt test
 &
sbt "testOnly /Users/user/Documents/Spark-Scala/Spark_Scala_Cucumber/src/test/scala/features/steps/testRunner.scala"

```
@RunWith(classOf[Cucumber])
@CucumberOptions(
  features = Array("classpath:features"),
  glue = Array("classpath:features.steps"),
  tags = Array("@my-tag"),
  monochrome = true,
  plugin = Array("pretty",
    "html:target/cucumber",
    "json:target/cucumber/test-report.json",
    "junit:target/cucumber/test-report.xml")
)
class testRunner {}
```

Path for this file:
/Users/user/Documents/Spark-Scala/Spark_Scala_Cucumber/src/test/scala/features/steps/testRunner.scala

Expecting this should be executed command line and cucumber report is generated command line.

Comment: Can you run regular JUnit tests?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I found the solution.. below is my answer

Answer (score 1):

I missed to add the dependency in build.sbt
I found this solution which was answered earlier by below thread:

[How do you run cucumber with Scala 2.11 and sbt 0.13?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33020504/how-do-you-run-cucumber-with-scala-2-11-and-sbt-0-13)

dependency to be added to build.sbt:

```
"com.novocode" % "junit-interface" % "0.11" % Test
```

With this dependency the code can be executed via command line :

```
 sbt test
```

This will execute all the scenarios/feature files, mentioned tags from src/test/scala/features folders.